# Unable to run WebDriver tests in Safari

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, safari, safaridriver

I'm trying to run the Webdriver tests in Safari. Although the browsers opens i'm seeing the message

[  0.007s] [safaridriver.client] Requesting connection at ws://localhost:48726...
[  2.513s] [safaridriver.client] Unable to establish a connection with the SafariDriver

I'm working with webdriver 2.33 and Safari version 5.1.7

Can someone point me what could be the issue?

Thanks
Anil

Answer (score 2):

I was facing similar issue with 2.31.0.
http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=5318
Downgrading  "selenium-webdriver" to  "2.27.0" for safari tests fixed my issue