# org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException on Selenium and Safari

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, safaridriver

I am trying to execute a few test scenarios on Safari-MAC using Selenium-2.4.0 and Cucumber.

I have created the extension of Safari browser and used the following code:

```
@Given("^Time (\\d+).$")
public void Time_(int time) throws Throwable {

    System.setProperty("webdriver.safari.driver",path_to_extension/SafariExtension/SafariDriver.safariextz");

    WebDriver driver = new SafariDriver();
    driver.get("www.google.com");
}
```

A Safari window is opened with following message:

```
[  0.020s] [safaridriver.client] Requesting connection at ws://localhost:7039...
[  2.546s] [safaridriver.client] Unable to establish a connection with the SafariDriver
```

And following is the error stack:

```
org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Failed to connect to SafariDriver after 45062 ms
Build info: version: '2.40.0', revision: '4c5c0568b004f67810ee41c459549aa4b09c651e', time: '2014-02-19 11:13:01'
System info: host: 'host-name', ip: 'xxx.xx.xx.xx', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.8.2', java.version: '1.6.0_65'
Driver info: driver.version: SafariDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverCommandExecutor.start(SafariDriverCommandExecutor.java:122)
    at org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver.startClient(SafariDriver.java:72)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:112)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:117)
    at org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver.<init>(SafariDriver.java:58)
    at org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver.<init>(SafariDriver.java:42)
    at foo.FirstStepDef.Time_(FirstStepDef.java:20)
    at ?.Given Time 10.(First.feature:4)
```

Please help in getting resolve the above problem

Comment: is your system's safari up to date?

Comment: I am using Safari 6.0.1

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to run Webdriver tests in Safari](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17716927/unable-to-run-webdriver-tests-in-safari)